# Connecting to EventStoreDB from Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, eventstoredb

I have EventStoreDB running in a local Kubernetes cluster, installed using [this Helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/eventstore/eventstore). Port-forwarding on 2113 allows me to access the admin dashboard as expected at `localhost:2113/web/index.html`

I am now trying to connect to this running instance from a Spring Boot microservice running in the same cluster. I am using this dependency of the EventStoreDB client

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.eventstore</groupId>
  <artifactId>db-client-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And I have the following code snippet which attempts to establish a connection and publish an event. However when triggering this, `appendToStream()` hangs indefinitely

```
EventStoreDBClientSettings settings = EventStoreDBClientSettings.builder()
  .addHost("localhost", 1113)
  .tls(false)
  .defaultCredentials("admin", "changeit")
  .maxDiscoverAttempts(1)
  .buildConnectionSettings();
EventStoreDBClient client = EventStoreDBClient.create(settings);
AppendToStreamOptions appendToStreamOptions = AppendToStreamOptions.get().expectedRevision(ExpectedRevision.noStream());
client.appendToStream("some-stream", appendToStreamOptions, eventData).get();
```

And for clarity, here is the declaration of `eventData`, where `{myObject}` is a domain object.

```
final EventData eventData = EventData.builderAsJson(UUID.randomUUID(), "some-event", {myObject}).build();
```

I have also tried using connection strings rather than the client to establish the connection settings, as is suggested in several places.

```
String connectionString = esdb://localhost:2113?tls=false
EventStoreDBConnectionString.parseOrThrow(connectionString);
```

I have also tried using `tcp` connection strings

```
ConnectTo=tcp://localhost:1113; UseSslConnection=false;
```

However I believe these are now unsupported in favor of using the client, as suggested [here](https://www.eventstore.com/blog/event-store-tcp-client-has-been-deprecated)

No exceptions are thrown, the execution just hangs indefinitely which is presumably caused by `appendToStream().get()` awaiting a response from the `CompleteableFuture`.

The admin dashboard shows no connections and no streams when viewed in a browser.

Note that I have tried both ports 1113 and 2113 in all cases. Does anyone have any ideas why  I can't connect or publish an event?

EDIT: JDK 21.0.1 and ESDB 4.1.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is probably caused by the version of the esdb server referenced in the Helm chart. The Helm chart points to an old version of esdb that is no longer supported and instead should point to `eventstore/eventstore:latest`.

Comment: Updated my question to include the JDK and ESDB versions. However, this isn't really an answer and is probably better served as a comment

Comment: esdb version 4.x is not supported, you should upgrade to 23.10.

Comment: FWIW I am not allowed to add a comment to the original post, as I don't have the reputation level required.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that ESDB v4.x is deprecated. I didn't realise the Helm chart was so outdated. Unfortunately it seems ESDB has deprecated support for Helm charts altogether in favour of a K8S operator, which is currently unavailable

Comment: If you edit your answer to indicate that the ESDB version in the Helm chart is the issue, I would be happy to accept it

Comment: Thanks Scott, I updated the answer as you suggested.